# Can't build a container from the Dockerfile

Tags: docker

I am working on a Linux Mint 17 machine and I am using Docker for the first time, so please bear with me.

I have just installed Docker like this (basically just followed the documentation):

```
sudo apt-get install docker.io
sudo ln -sf /usr/bin/docker.io /usr/local/bin/docker
sudo sed -i '$acomplete -F _docker docker' /etc/bash_completion.d/docker.io
```

Then I try to build my container:

```
docker build -t myproject .
```

But I get this error message:

```
ricardo@toshi:~/workspace/myproj > docker build -t myproject .
Uploading context 94.72 kB
Uploading context 
Step 0 : FROM ubuntu:14.04
 ---> ba5877dc9bec
Step 1 : RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y php5-cli php5-dev php-pear wget build-essential
 ---> Running in 729afe65b3f5
2014/07/26 18:38:05 no such file or directory
2014/07/26 20:38:05 The command [/bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install -y php5-cli php5-dev php-pear wget build-essential] returned a non-zero code: 1
ricardo@toshi:~/workspace/myproject >
```

This is how the `Dockerfile` looks like:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y php5-cli php5-dev php-pear wget build-essential
RUN wget http://www.xmailserver.org/libxdiff-0.23.tar.gz && tar xvzf libxdiff-0.23.tar.gz && cd libxdiff-0.23 && ./configure && make && make install
RUN pecl install xdiff-1.5.2
RUN echo extension=xdiff.so >> /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/xdiff.ini
RUN php -r "readfile('https://getcomposer.org/installer');" | php -- --install-dir=/bin --filename=composer

WORKDIR /app
ENV PORT 5000
CMD composer install && php bin/server.php
```

The error message, as shown above, says:

```
no such file or directory
The command [/bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install -y php5-cli php5-dev php-pear wget build-essential] returned a non-zero code: 1
```

but I really don't know what exactly doesn't exist or what am I missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed `lxc`, tried again building the container and it worked.

```
sudo apt-get install lxc
```